# Why isn't a StopIteration raised here?

Tags: python, iterator

Take a look at this, the crux of the question is at the bottom:

```
>>> scan = iter('FHUR203459')
>>> while True:
        print(next(scan))


F
H
U
R
2
0
3
4
5
9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 2, in <module>
    print(next(scan))
StopIteration
>>> scan = iter('FHUR203459')
>>> for i in range(12):  # 12 * 2 for each join is 24, much longer than the string; should raise error.
        print(''.join(next(scan) for i in range(2)))


FH
UR
20
34
59







>>>
```

In other words, we can see that the iterator reaches its end in both situations, however it only raises a `StopIteration` in the first, even though `next()` is used in both situations after it reached the end. Why does using it in `join` seem to evade the error? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, the `StopIteration` is not handled anywhere. But in the second case,

```
''.join(next(scan) for i in range(2))
```

we pass *a generator expression* to the `''.join`, which handles the `StopIteration` raised by `next(scan)` and exits every time. That is why `''.join` produces empty strings.

You can slightly modify the same, and pass a list to `''.join` and see the exception being raised, yourself, like this

```
>>> scan = iter('FHUR203459')
>>> for i in range(12):
...     print(''.join([next(scan) for i in range(2)]))
... 
FH
UR
20
34
59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 2, in <listcomp>
StopIteration
```

It shows that the `StopIteration` is actually raised, and *List Comprehension* takes the hit, this time.

Answer (score 2):

`str.join()` calls `list()` on the generator, and that call swallows the `StopIteration`.

Anything that *consumes* an iterator *must* catch `StopIteration`; it doesn't matter then exactly what raised the exception; the generator expression or anything *used* by the generator expression:

```
>>> def raises_stopiteration(): raise StopIteration
... 
>>> next(raises_stopiteration() for _ in range(10))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in raises_stopiteration
StopIteration
>>> list(raises_stopiteration() for _ in range(10))
[]
```

Comment: really? `str.join` listifies`?! Then why use a generator at all? What would be the advantage of using a generator over a list comprehension within `str.join`?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: yes, it listifies because it has to pre-calculate the output size before copying in the strings. Using a list comprehension instead of a generator expression is therefor *faster* when using `str.join()` on the result.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget `str.join` has to know the length of the string in advance to join. So, if we pass a list, it just has to do one iteration otherwise, it converts it to a list and does another pass to find the size of the joined string.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: see [Raymond Hettinger's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024).